# I've these Kendo radio buttons and they select just the first radio button value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've these Kendo radio buttons and they select just the first radio button value 
here is the snap 
[Please check this picture](http://prntscr.com/4qh59z)
It always gets the the first value to save not the rest, even if they are checked, I also tried by make one true then it just send the value that is permanently true, even if I change it won't work.

Here is the radio button code

```
<td class="span2">
    @Html.Label("lblType","Select Document Type")
</td>
<td>
    @Html.RadioButton("docType", "SA")Service Agreement
    <br />
    @Html.RadioButton("docType", "W9")W9
    <br />
    @Html.RadioButton("docType", "COI")Certificate of Insurance
    <br />
    @Html.RadioButton("docType", "WC")Workers Comp
    <br />
    @Html.RadioButton("docType", "Other")Other    
</td>
```

This is the java script. UrlDrop is the function that has the url, I used it with out the function but that didn't worked either.

```
function UrlDrop() {
    return '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Vendor")?id=' + id + "&documentType=" + $("#docType").val(); //is(":checked"); //val();
}

//alert($("#docType").val());

$(function () {
    $('#dropZone').filedrop({

        url:UrlDrop ,//'@*@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Vendor", new { id = TempData["VendorId"], docTypes= (("docType:checked"))})*@',
        paramname: 'files',
        maxFiles: 10,
        dragOver: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', '#71b43b');
        },
        dragLeave: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', '#dbf0cb');
        },
        drop: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', '#dbf0cb');
        },
        afterAll: function () {
            $('#dropZone').html('The file(s) have been uploaded successfully!');
            var grid = $("#VendorAttachmentGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.page(1);
            grid.dataSource.read();
        },
        uploadFinished: function (i, file, response, time) {
            $('#uploadResult').append('<li>' + file.name + '</li>');
        }
    });
```

here is the controller. It always gets the the first value to save not the rest, even if they are checked.

```
 public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable files, long id, string documentType="")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.RadioButton` generates a *group* of radio-buttons which can be accessed by its `name` (and not `id`).

So you have to get the value like this :

```
function UrlDrop() {
    var docType = $("input[name='docType']:checked").val();
    return '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Vendor")?id=' + id + "&documentType=" + docType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("radiobutton_legal").Checked(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "search_type" }).Label("Физлицо"))
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                 @(Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("radiobutton_entity").Checked(false).HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "search_type" }).Label("Юрлицо"))
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                 @(Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("radiobutton_cooperative").Checked(false).HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "search_type" }).Label("ЖСК"))

-----

function addAddressData() {
        var search_type = 0;
        if ($("#radiobutton_legal").prop('checked')) {
            search_type = 1
        } else if ($("#radiobutton_entity").prop('checked')) {
            search_type = 2
        }
        else if ($("#radiobutton_cooperative").prop('checked')) {
            search_type = 3
        }
        return {
            keyword: $("#autocomplete_address").val(),
            search_type: search_type
        }
    }
```